# How can I have two <div> elements side-by-side (2 columns)

Tags: css

I would like to have two  tags side-by-side as if being two columns.

So far I have

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="1">text here</div>
    <div id="2">text here</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

What I'm having difficulty with is the CSS for the divs. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the `float` property.

Quick example:

```
#1, #2 {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
}
```

Check out this [beginner tutorial on CSS Floats](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/).

Answer (score 3):

May be you can try:

```
div#wrapper { 
  display: table; 
}

div#wrapper div { 
   display: table-cell; 
   padding: 5px; 
}
```

or this one:

```
div#wrapper div { 
  display: inline-block; 
}
```

Comment: The inline-block option is cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

As a start:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div style="float:left;" id="1">text here</div>
  <div style="float:left;" id="2">text here</div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
#1 {
float: left;
width: 50%;
}

#2 {
float: left;
width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `float:left` in conjunction with `overflow-x:hidden;` like so:

```
#1 {
    float:left
}
#2 {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add the following to your divs:

```
style="float:left"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#1, #2 { 
  display: inline-block; 
}
```

Given that both #1 and #2 divs have a total width of not greater than the parent div.

If you use float, you will end up changing them to inline-block once you have to position a child div into absolute.